# Is it possible to provide a URL that returns an m3u8 file to azure media player?

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I'm using azure media player to play AES encrypted videos on my website. However, I don't want to use the default HLS streaming uri that comes back.

What I'm doing is loading the m3u8 from the HLS endpoint and adding captions to it directly (Since I can't find a way to add captions through media services itself, if there is one, I'd be all ears). So the url looks something like this: https://website.com/getvideo/100000

This url returns a valid m3u8 file and I can get it playing in other players (unencrypted).

My question is this: Is there a way to get azure media player to recognize this url as a valid return of an m3u8 file? Currently it's not even trying to hit my endpoint and I suspect it's because it's looking for something in the url.

Let me know if you need more information.